# How to put a clean install of Windows 11 on a computer with untrustworthy OEM?

Tags: windows-11, license, oem, bloatware

I have a computer that came with Windows 11 installed, but is from a company that has had a reputation for installing backdoors and bloatware in the OS.

Is there a legal route I can completely wipe this manufacturer's copy of Windows 11, and install a clean, trusted version of Windows, without having to buy a brand new license?

Comment: For the majority of machines it is as simple as going to Microsoft and [creating Windows 11 Install Media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows11) and then booting your machine from USB to install it. During that process you will be able to delete all existing partitions and install "from scratch". If you don't trust your existing install then I would create the install media on a machine you do trust. If your machine is a some kind of special (non-standard) build then it may require install media from your manufacturer. We would need to know more to tell for sure.

Comment: And there's something you need to know: Windows HAS backdoors no matter where you source it from. Whatever vendors may or may not add it's a moot point.

Comment: @ChanganAuto sources?

Comment: @Albin FBI, CIA, NSA and any cybersecurity expert in the world including Linus Torvalds who has been asked many times to include the same in the LInux kernel.

Comment: @ChanganAuto referencing names of persons or organizations are not what I consider valid sources. If you make such a statement please elaborate, otherwise, it's just a superficial comment and should be removed.

Comment: @Albin Does an old MSM news article good for you? If so here's one of the thousands that you and anybody else can find just by googling (of course, reality is almost always much worse than this "harmless" leaks. Wikileaks - and Snowden - has extensive research over leaked information from the aforementioned 3-letter agencies):   https://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/jul/11/microsoft-nsa-collaboration-user-data And all of this pretty much any cybersecurity expert worth their salt already knows or at least strongly suspects. And no, we DON'T do the same (we have other means LOL)

Comment: @ChanganAuto no, from a first glance it's not, decrypting intercepted skype messages is something completely different than a backdoor into an OS. PS. I'm well aware of quite a few security risks in Windows, I think you missed my point.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have proof of purchase and backup your product key (just in case) via `wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey` and registry (`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform` in `BackupProductKeyDefault`) or [ShowKeyPlus](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/showkeyplus/9PKVZCPRX9NV?hl=en-us&gl=US).

After that you can follow Mokubai advice from the comments, just be aware that (depending on your laptop model) you might need additional drivers during the installation process e.g. RAID controllers etc. (installation might not be possible without those):

- [create an installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows11)
- using the installation media boot into the command line (repair -> troubleshoot -> advanced options -> command prompt) and clean the HD using diskpart
- Do a regular installation using the installation media
- Don't forget to update, set up security measures, etc.

Be aware that there can be other security risks you might not get rid of by installing a fresh OS. If you don't trust a vendor don't give him access to your HW!